# Xcode: What determines the order of GPX files in the Debug > Simulate Location menu?

Tags: xcode, location, simulation, gpx

I have a list of a couple dozen .gpx files added to my Xcode project for location simulation, and I have assigned them all different names corresponding to their locations.

But if I go to Debug > Simulate Location, the order of the gpx files appears to be totally random. This makes it slightly more difficult to find the location I want because I have to skim through the list every time.

They aren't sorted alphabetically, they don't seem to be sorted by location, and they aren't sorted according to the order in the Project Navigator. Are they really just random? Also there is a name field in the .gpx file, but that doesn't seem to make any difference either (the menu just uses the name of the file, not the name in the field inside the file).

Comment: Seems to me this is just a bug … submitted a report.

Answer (score 2):

This is finally resolved in the Xcode 9.3 beta

Comment: Is it sorted alphabetically in the beta?

Comment: Yes, the GPX files are sorted alphabetically